# Other than Magento Connect, does anything else create maintenance.flag?

Tags: maintenance

A site I have been involved with has twice in the last couple of weeks gone into maintenance mode due to the presence of the maintenance.flag file.

Neither time has anybody been installing / upgrading anything through Magento Connect which is the usual culprit for this, so was wondering if there are other parts of Magento that set this flag for any reason?

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: grep your installation for `maintenance.flag` string. Normally it has to be found in `index.php`, backup helper and magento connect. Anything else would be your clue.

Answer (score 3):

The auto backup procedure can also create the `maintenance.flag` if the setting from `System->Configuration->System->Scheduled Backup Settings->Maintenance Mode` is set to `Yes`.
Also the manual backup procedure does it if you specify it.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately on this store the scheduled backup is off and no manual ones had been performed when it occurred.